# How can I set a root page outside of tabs that don't keep the tabs in place?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic2-tabs

The flow of my app means that there are no tabs in place until a user logs in.  The first page is a full-screen login screen.  Once logged in the user is taken to `tabs.ts` which holds my tabs code.

One of the tabs has a button in that logs users out:

user.ts:

```
  // Logout
  logout() {    
    // Log the user out
    this.user.logout();

    // Take user to login screen
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }
```

I thought that setting the root to `LoginPage`, which isn't part of any tab page, would remove the tabs.  Unfortunately not, and the tabs remain.  This is really problematic for obvious reasons.

How can I remove the tabs from this point?  I feel like I need to potentially grab the tabs instance and destroy it, but that's a guess and I'm struggling to find anything in the docs.

Comment: do you want to hide the tab in LoginPage?

Comment: Please see reference link how I can solve issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249315/how-to-navigate-page-without-top-tabs-app-components-root

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After posting this I found the answer on the Ionic forums.

Effectively, each tab maintains its own navigation stack, which I was aware of but I expected the `setRoot` to bypass the stack.  Logically, it does not.

Instead, you need to call `getRootNav().setRoot()` on your `App`.

`App` is imported from `ionic-angular`, and then passed to your controller.

A full (albeit truncated) example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {

  constructor(
    private app: App
  ) {

  }

  // Logout
  logout() {
    // Take user to login screen
    this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
  }

}
```

Comment: That's right, `this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);` is the proper way to do that. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular router and navigate the user to login page once logout button is clicked.

```
this.router.navigate(["login"]).
```

Place proper routing guards so that user is not able to access the route if not logged in. 
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Ionic uses a custom implementation of the router (NavController), so this answer wouldn't be right for Ionic.