# How to navigate Page without Top Tabs App.components root

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 , VS code IDE recently I came issue regards navigation to setRoot from root Tab page to another page (Home Page) without Top Tabs how could I achieve ?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { UserTabsPage } from '../pages/user-tab/user-tabs';
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = UserTabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {}
}
```

**UserTabsPage.ts**

```
export class UserTabsPage { 
tab1Root = UserLoginPage;   
tab2Root =LoginPage;  
 constructor() { } 
}
```

**UserTabsPage.html**

```
 <ion-content padding center text-center>
    <ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" >
      <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="User Login"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Phone Login"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs> </ion-content>
```

**userLogin.ts**

```
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
     private registerPage(){
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(RegisterPage );}
```

**userLogin.html**

```
> <button ion-button clear ion-button item-end icon-start color="dark"
> (click)="registerPage()" >Sign Up?</button>
```

**My Register Page result :**[image]

**My Expected Register Page Result:**[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.component.ts` you need to set your `rootPage` to `RegisterPage`

You could do this via the `Events` module/component that comes with Ionic.

**userLogin.ts**

```
constructor(private events: Events){ }

public registerPage() {
  this.events.publish('Register');
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(..., private events: Events) {
  this.initEvents();
}

private initEvents() {
  this.events.subscribe('Register', () => {
    this.rootPage = RegisterPage;
  });
}
```

Anything that is subscribed to the `'Register'` event, will be notified when that event is published.

Comment: No worries, remember to mark it as correct in case someone else comes by this question :)